# How to run only selected scripts in selenium grid

Tags: testing, selenium, ant, webdriver

I can run all the selenium scripts in a directory using `ant`, but I want to know is there a way to run only some of the files in that directory.

Is there a way to specify scripts to run having some special pattern in their names or only first or last 10 numbers of scripts.

I am using `ant` to run these scripts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only ant and no other framework like testng or junit, then i guess you can achieve this by creating seperate ant tasks to run all or selected scripts and then pass the task name from command line. refer to official ant documentation.

If you are using testng, then it allows you to create groups based on different criteria, refer to testng.org